# Iterating MultiMap in Java

Tags: java, iterator, multimap

I have a multimap like below:

```
map = {config1=[abc, xyz], config2=[abc]}
```

Now I try to iterate it using the following piece of code

```
Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
          while(itr.hasNext()) { 
              Entry<String, Object> entry = itr.next();
              System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue()); 
              }
```

I am getting the output as:

```
Key = config1, Value = [abc, xyz]
Key = config2, Value = [abc]
```

but I need the output as:

```
Key = config1
Value = abc
Value = xyz
Key = config2
Value = abc
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    String[] arr1 = {"abc", "xyz"};
    String[] arr2 = {"abc"};
    map.put("config1", arr1);
    map.put("config2", arr2);

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = itr.next();
        System.out.println("entry.getKey() = " + entry.getKey());
        for (Object object: (Object[]) entry.getValue()) {
            System.out.println("object = " + object);
        }
    }
}
```

Then output will look like

```
entry.getKey() = config2
object = abc
entry.getKey() = config1
object = abc
object = xyz
```

The key action this is casting `String[]` to `Object[]`.